# SQL Server trigger Insert

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, triggers

Hello Database Masters:

Im a newbie to the SQL Server world. Basically I have a table with 3 columns
`CountryID`, `CountryName` and `Currency`.

In the `insert` I will just insert two values for `CountryName` and `Currency` and `CountryID` will populate automatically using a trigger eg:

```
CYYYYMMDDHHSS (Code|Year|Month|Day|Hour|Seconds)
```

Can some expert help me with my problem?

Comment: Are you having trouble setting up a trigger, or learning how to parsing a CYYYYMMDDHHSS string into multiple database fields?

Comment: What is the `code` part of your `CountryID` column? Where does that come from?? It would be **much easier** to have just a simple `INT IDENTITY` as your primary key in this table - "constructing" these kind of "unique ID's" manually is error-prone, hard to do, extremely hard to maintain, and will always in some way come back and bite you.....

Comment: Are you sure you want a trigger and not a computed column?